# IShowing $F(t)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_ke^{ikt}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|<2$. For real $t$, let $F(t)=f(e^{it})$. Show that for each $t$, $$F(t)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_ke^{ikt} \space \space  where \space  \space a_k=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} F(\theta)e^{-ik \theta}d \theta$$ Do I have to use Cauchy's Integral Formula to prove this?

Comment: Isn't this Fourier formula??

Comment: Yes. But I don't think we have to know anything about Fourier to prove this. It really is a complex analysis problem.

Comment: if the $F(t)$ is analytic, then it must have Laurent expansion, just set $|z| = 1 $, for coefficients, divide it again by $z^{\mathrm{something}}$ and calculate the residues, that will give you coefficients.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I'm not sure what you mean by dividing by $z^{something}$. Divide $a_k$ by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function $f(z)$ is analytic in region $|z|<2$, it has a Laurent expansion, $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ in this region.

If we set $f(z) = f(e^{i\theta})$, we get $F(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n e^{int}$. Multiplying both sides, by $e^{-imt}$ and integrating between $-\pi \to \pi$ and using orthogonality of $e^{i m t}$, we get the values of $c_n$.

Or just, let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ where $c_n = f^n(0)/n!$

Using Cauchy integral formula, we get, $c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i } \oint \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$, choosing the path around $0$  as $e^{i \theta}$ (since numerator is analytic) gives you your required value.

Comment: When you say "choose the path around $0$ as $e^{i \theta}$" are just referring to $- \pi$ to $\pi$?

Comment: @User69127 yes ${{{{{{}}}}}}$